# Ruby process eat 100% cpu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpu, mongrel

When im trying to logout from my app (using devise) rails application hangs and ruby eat 100% of CPU, after im restarting server it's stil frezeed(cant load page). It gone only when im drop and recreate my database. Im using PostgreSQL, trying to switch to MySQL, didnt help. Use mongrel(happens with webrick too). Ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.9

strace

```
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xe1c3fc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0x2)                       = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
futex(0xe1c3fc, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1c458, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0xe1be68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
```

console output:

```
Started GET "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-09 10:11:13 +0200
  SQL (1.0ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"jokes"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms
```

Im not really sure what happens there?

UPD* This is freeze happens not only on logout, it's happens randomly :( Also other developer on mac havent this problem, im running Ubuntu 11.10, tried on 10.04, still have it.

Comment: 100% cpu sounds like some kind of infinite loop, and there are countless possible culprits as to what could cause that. Saving a model in an `after_save` hook is one, infinite redirect is another. This coulde be one of those, but it could also be something else completely (not even necessarily an infinite loop, for that matter).

Comment: i check twice, there is no infinity loops on hooks

Comment: Can you show us the model code for user model? What you've given us isn't enough for us to even begin to pinpoint where the error is coming from.

Comment: please see update, i think this is someting linux-related

Comment: Ruby eating 100% could mean just one thing: your server is a single core :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on  cache_classes in development.rb